# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF' when using jdbc

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, pyspark

I have a problem when trying to connect to sql server through jdbc over pyspark. My query contains an IF ELSE statement
Here is the code:

```
df = spark.read.jdbc(
        table="""(IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                 FROM {database}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
                                 AND  TABLE_NAME = '{predict_table_name}'))
                BEGIN

                <Some query here >

                END

                ELSE
                BEGIN

                <Some other query here >

                END) as a""".format(database = db, predict_table_name = predict_table_name),
        **conn_params
)
```

I got an error like this:

> oop/appcache/application_1564676657552_0009/container_1564676657552_0009_02_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
>   py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o83.jdbc.
>   : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.

Does this mean I cannot use "IF" in the jdbc statement? Can you help me with an alternative way?

Comment: If you were running that query in SSMS you wouldn't have brackets around your `IF` nor would you have `as a`.

Comment: Thanks @DaleBurrell ! It’s not run in SSMS. Maybe JDBC is treating this query as a sub query and that’s why the IF ELSE statement cannot run.